# Synchronous mode disruptor for testing purposes

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern

In order to unit-test some code that contains a disruptor I need to make sure that events published to the disruptor get handled before the main test thread continues (obviously, I'm not testing the disruptor code).

In the absence of a more elegant solution, I overcame the problem as follows:

```
...
ringBuffer.publish(sequence);
while (ringBuffer.getBufferSize() > ringBuffer.remainingCapacity()) {
    Thread.yield();
}
```

However, I was wondering if there some way to set the disruptor to "synchronous mode" (I looked but couldn't find any), or a "synchronous mock disruptor" implementation that is available for use that would ensure that the thread will not return from `publish()` before all events have been processed by `onEvent()`?

Answer (score 1):

The disruptor doesn't have a synchronous mode.

There are various ways to fudge one:

- Such as blocking the publisher on a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) which the event handler counts down.
- Another alternative is to use a same thread executor, such as this one from [jmock](http://www.jmock.org/javadoc/jmock-2.6.0/doc/org/jmock/lib/concurrent/DeterministicExecutor.html), for the disruptor to schedule the event handlers on. Thus you control when the event his processed by the event handler.

However that feels more like an integration test than a unit test to me. Why does the publisher need to "know" the consumer has consumed the event?

Comment: I think the test qualifies as a unit test since I'm testing a specific functionality within a single class. The publisher needs to know the event have been consumed since that specific functionality is only relevant afterwards (the publisher in this case is the test thread itself).

Comment: If I understand correctly, your first suggestion requires changing the event handler, which doesn't make sense to me (since this is required for testing only). I tried your 2nd suggestion using Guava's `MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService()`. However this causes the Disruptor to get stuck on `Disruptor.start()`.

Comment: Sorry I assumed you were testing the publisher. If your testing the eventHandler you can just invoke `onEvent` method with an arbitrary sequence number no need for inter thread comunication.

Comment: That's an interesting idea but it would require me to change the structure of the code I'm testing since my `EventHandler<>` class is a currently a private inner class (and there's no reason to expose it except for the testing). Fortunately, I can (and will) do that, but I wish there was a more elegant solution. Anyway +1 for the effort and the interesting ideas you brought.